# Indexed mode is reducing image to only 2 colors

Tags: image-processing, gimp

I created a new palette in gimp using my original RGB image (containing shades of yellow and black) which gave me about ~200 colors (with interval=2 in Import dialog). 
Then I changed the mode from RGB to Indexed using the palette I created above, but the resulting image contains only 2 colors - black and yellow. All the dark-greys, light-greys and different yellows are absent.

I want my indexed image to resemble the RGB as much as possible but the result looks disastrous. Please help.

Visual illustration of my problem : http://i49.tinypic.com/w1tchw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the original image, it looks like you're working with layers where the top layer is a greenish yellow and the bottom layer is black, and the shapes and patterns are defined by their transparency. You would need to combine the two layers into one. I'm afraid I don't know Gimp so I can't give specific instructions.

Comment: You were right, there were just two colors with varying transparency as opposed to multiple shades like i had assumed. I had to 'flatten' the image to proceed, which worked. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

When converting to Indexed Mode select a `Dithering` option.

Comment: That's just going to give you a pattern of the same 2 colors, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that gives just 2 colors again. The problem was the alpha channel.